# Why do python enum members have an infinite recursion of all members as attributes?

Tags: python, enums

Python enum members have all others members of the enum as attributes, including themselves, and those have too. So there is an infinite recursion of all members.

```
from enum import Enum

class TT(Enum):
    m1 = 1
    m2 = 2
    m3 = 3
    
t1 = TT['m1']
t1.m2.m3.m3.m1.m2.m2.m1.m3.value
>>> 3
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the class attributes from the instances of the class.

So if you evaluate `t1.m2`, you're accessing the class attribute `TT.m2`. If you evaluate `t1.m2.m3`, you're accessing `TT.m2` and then `TT.m3`.

You get the same thing with non-enum class whose fields are instances of the class.

```
class Foo:
    pass
Foo.A = Foo()
Foo.B = Foo()
Foo.C = Foo()

Foo.A.B.C.A.C is Foo.C # True
```

Enums give you a structure like this.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. You're showing **what** happens, not why it happens. I think what I'm looking for involves a bit more of an explanation of what enum members actually are in relation to the class. They're not normal class instances. You wouldn't see this behaviour if you'd remove the Enum inheritance from the class declaration.

Comment: Yes you would, if you created a class whose class attributes were instances of that class.

Comment: I see. So the only difference with enums is the syntax to create the instances.

Comment: @mahkitah Not the only difference, but this is why you get the behaviour you asked about.

Comment: Yes, I can see where the recursion comes from now.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is performance.  Storing the enum members in the class dictionary makes accessing them several times faster.  It's also convenient when adding behavior to be able to access one member directly from another.

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.